# python generate SQL statement keywords by given lists

Tags: python, sql, list, keyword

I have below variables try to make an auto generating SQL statement in python

```
_SQL_fields         =   ("ID", "NAME", "BIRTH", "SEX", "AGE")
_add_SQL_desc_type  =   ("PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREASEMENT",)
_SQL_type           =   ("INT",'TEXT')
_Value              =   (1,'TOM',19700101,'M',40)

bop = ["AND"] * (len(_SQL_fields) - 1) 
mop = ["="] * 5
comma = [","] * 4

exception_field = ["NAME", "BIRTH"]
```

for successful design a SQL statement I need below strings generated by above variable:

```
'(ID, NAME, BIRTH, SEX, AGE)'
'(ID PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREASEMENT INT, NAME TEXT, BIRTH, SEX, AGE)'
'ID = 1 AND NAME = "TOM" AND BIRTH = "19700101" AND SEX = "M" AND AGE = '40''
```

and removed exception_field strings may looks like

```
'(ID, SEX, AGE)'
'(ID PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREASEMENT INT, SEX, AGE)'
'ID = 1 AND SEX = "M" AND AGE = '40''
```

==========

so far I use something like

```
str(zip(_SQL_fields,_add_SQL_desc_type,_SQL_type,comma))
```

or using

```
", ".join(_SQL_fields)
```

to get one.

but I get a lot of mess when, especiall in processing the "comma" and "quotes".

```
'(ID, NAME, BIRTH, SEX, AGE)'    <===== this is OK for SQL
'(ID, NAME, BIRTH, SEX, AGE,)'    <===== this is NOT
```

and this

```
'ID = 1 AND NAME = "TOM" AND BIRTH = "19700101" AND SEX = "M" and AGE = '40'  
                   ^-some var need quotes and some do no need them.
```

So anyone can share me how to write a clean code for generate above strings?

Thanks for your time!

KC

Comment: are you tied to the variables the way you have them, or are they under your control?

Comment: Thanks, those fields and other variable are under control but I want it be more flexible, also a lot of strA + strB + strC way may looks too complex. 
to be frank, in simple way I can write 'ID = 1 AND NAME = "TOM" AND BIRTH = "19700101" AND SEX = "M" AND AGE = '40'' then pass it to SQL query directly, but that is not what I want, I want system can generate SQL by give logistics in static or dynamic way.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you look at ORM. I used SQLAlchemy for a little while and found it satisfactory. I'm currently playing around with stuff like what you are asking for and I can say that It is challenging. That way lies meta classes, descriptors and all sorts of black magic.

Comment: I've readed the ORM modules before, but found they may not store data as plan db table also they may heavy. I will keep trying, thanks!

Comment: The problem is that anything that you write will probably either be heavy as well or will end up being as inconvenient to work with as vanilla SQL and less maintainable. There are a ton of corner cases.

Comment: aaronasterling, by your suggestion I've read the document of ORM\SQLAlchemy again, seems what I want to do is what SQLAlchemy has already done, it is my fault and prejudice, many thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain

```
'(ID PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREASEMENT INT, NAME TEXT, BIRTH, SEX, AGE)'
```

you can use [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from itertools module in python.

Then, to remove exception_fields in the obtain list, you can use set or list comprehension.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [2, 3]
l3 = list(set(l1) - set(l2))
print l3
--> [1, 4]

l3 = [val for val in l1 if val not in l2]
print l3
--> [1, 4]
```

I recommend the list comprehension.

```
", ".join(_SQL_fields)
```

is perfect to obtain

```
'ID, NAME, BIRTH, SEX, AGE'
```

so i don't really understand you're problem.

Comment: thanks ohe. my problem can be solved by the ORM : SQLAlchemy now.